# Start a process in a VB form without clicking a button

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Here is my situation.

I have a windows from application in VB.NET. In the my first form there are two checkboxes. If the one is checked it goes to Form2, if only the second one is checked it goes to Form3. If both are checked then i want first to go on Form2 and when this process is finished go to Form3. All good until this point. 
However, I want Form3 to start executing its code (which is inside a background worker) without pressing any button (which is the case when only the second checkbox is checked). Is this possible?

Thanks In advance!

Extra info....

To navigate between the Forms I use a Show/hide/Close scheme. For example:

`If CheckBoxTrain.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then 
            Me.Hide()
            Form2.Show()
        ElseIf CheckBoxTrain.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked And CheckBoxEvaluate.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
            Me.Hide()
            Form3.Show()`

At the end of the code in form2 i check if the second checkbox is also checked:

```
If Form1.CheckBoxTrain.CheckState = CheckState.Checked And Form1.CheckBoxEvaluate.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
            Form3.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End If
```

Then in Form3 there is a button in which after pressing it i have all the code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i = 1 To n_monte

        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button2.Enabled = True

        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True

        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

    Next
End Sub
```

All i want is for this last piece of code is to start running without pressing any buttons (only for the case in which both checkboxes are checked)

Comment: Please provide more detail. Please provide the code where you're making use of your `BackgroundWorker`, for example. Also please elaborate on what you mean by "...is checked it goes to Form3" - you haven't told us how you're navigating between forms.

Comment: Information is not sufficient..provide some code..

Comment: i would say it is possible based on what you have said, although, some code would be more useful.

Comment: In your form2, just refrence the process you want to kick off in the form2 code. should work.

Comment: I editted my post, containing some piece of code.....Thanks again!

Comment: Johny, i can't really do this, because backgroundworker classes are private subs and can only be called by the form they belong to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a `Boolean` property in `Form3` and set that property in `Form1` based on whether or not both `CheckBoxes` are checked.  In the `Load` event handler of `Form3`, start the `BackgroundWorker` or don't based on the value of that property.

Comment: Thanks a lot....it seems rather basic now, but for some reason didn't cross my mind